# SQL - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know what's the problem in this code... I verified all columns names and data types but this not work

```
CREATE TABLE empleado (
    tipo_dni VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nro_dni INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    telefono INT NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tipo_dni , nro_dni)
);

CREATE TABLE director (
    tipo_dni VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nro_dni INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tipo_dni, nro_dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (tipo_dni)
        REFERENCES empleado (tipo_dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (nro_dni)
        REFERENCES empleado (nro_dni)
);
```

ERROR

```
#1005 - Can't create table `tpfinal`.`director` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: My error is in the director table.

#1005 - Can't create table `tpfinal`.`director` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You primary key is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (tipo_dni , nro_dni)
```

This is a composite primary key.  The foreign key reference should be composite as well:

```
FOREIGN KEY (tipo_dni, nro_dni)
    REFERENCES empleado (tipo_dni, nro_dni)
```

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly for me. So... when a have a composite primary key my foreign key should be declared how a composite foreign key.